# Java Generics: Type Extension In Method Declaration Parameters

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I am learning Java Generics.  My understanding is that Generics parameterize Collections by type.  In the Oracle tutorial there is the following comment:

> In generic code, the question mark (?), called the wildcard,
>   represents an unknown type.

On the next page there is the following example of method declaration with an upper-bounded wildcard in the parameters:

```
public void process(List<? extends Foo> list)
```

Given that, I am wondering why this method declaration is illegal:

```
public void process(List<E extends Number> list)
```

while this one is legal:

```
public <E extends Number> void process(List<E> list)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When specifying the method parm types, you're using the generic type, so it has to be defined upfront. In this statement, you use E without definition

```
public void process(List<E extends Number> list) { /* ... */ }
```

However, in the second one, it is defined before the method return type (void):

```
public <E extends Number> void process(List<E> list) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I think this is actually a restatement of the question.  Why, then, would a wildcard parameter be allowed without an "up front definition?"  Given that it is so allowed, why is such a restriction placed on "T?"

Comment: But wildcard is defined in the JVM. It is a special case, built into the language. T, on the other hand, is something you came up with, so you must tell Java what T is before using it. It could be simply <T> or more restricted <T extends Number>, but it has to be defined before usage.

Comment: Many thanks, phoenix.  I was considering both "T" and "?" as just tokens in Generics.  Google searches on the wildcard are dominated by posts about Generics that were affirming this notion.  Just now I Googled "java wildcard -generics" and found the java.lang.reflect interface WildcardType.  The documentation says: "WildcardType represents a wildcard type expression, such as ?, ? extends Number, or ? super Integer."  This is not clear to me.  Is "?" some kind of a built-in object that implements this interface?  My Java kung fu is very rusty. :-)

Answer (score 4):

There's not a much better answer than "because that was how the language was designed."  But one way of thinking about it is that type parameters are treated like another list of arguments to the method: they have to all appear at once, in one (ordered) list.

You can call generic methods by passing the type arguments explicitly: for example, `foo.<Integer, String>process(list)`.  That means that the type parameters have to have an explicit order, just like normal value arguments.

Answer (score 3):

To complete on @phoenix's answer, the problem in this statement

```
public void process(List<E extends Number> list) { /* ... */ }
```

is that the declaration of your generic type E is in the wrong place. The right place is before the return type:

```
public <E extends Number> void process(List<E> list) { /* ... */ }
```

However, another possible place to define your generic type would be in the class declaration itself:

```
class MyClass<E extends Number> {

    public void process(List<E> list) { /* ... */ }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Approximately both are same , but i am using first one only.